# Setting calendar order date with string value

Tags: android, calendar

I have been stuck for 2 days and finally give up. I need your help on the calendar function.  The person selects a product (on a button) and that sets a message and allows them to add a reminder when they can reorder it. Right now I have it opening the calendar but am unable to have the calendar set the date based on that product. I am unsure of how to set the string value, recall it, and have that set the calendar date.  I know this is basic stuff but I appreciate the help! Sorry for lengthy code. I want to make sure I included everything related.

Here is my code:

```
Button reorder1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rotramadol);
Button reorder2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roaciphex);
Button reorder3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roflexeril);
reorder1.setOnClickListener(this);
reorder2.setOnClickListener(this);
reorder3.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.rotramadol) {
//this one needs the calendar set 10 days from now
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(
                        "Order Quantity 90 tabs requires 10 days")
                .setTitle("Tramadol")
                .setPositiveButton("Set Reminder", this)
                .setNegativeButton("OK", this).setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        ad.show();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.roaciphex) {
//this one needs the calendar set 25 days from now
        AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Order Quantity 30 tabs requires 25 days")
                .setTitle("Aciphex")
                .setPositiveButton("Set Reminder", this)
                .setNegativeButton("OK", this).setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        ad1.show();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.roflexeril) {
//this one needs the calendar set 7 days from now
        AlertDialog ad2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Order Quantity 30 tabs requires 7 days")
                .setTitle("Flexeril")
                .setPositiveButton("Set Reminder", this)
                .setNegativeButton("OK", this).setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        ad2.show();


@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (which) {
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: // yes

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Reorder");
        intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "");
        intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,
                "https://www.place they reorder.com");

        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                calDate.getTimeInMillis());

        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

        intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1;");

        intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
        intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);

        startActivity(intent);

        break;

    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: // no

        dialog.cancel();

        break;
    default:
        break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to set a calendar event based on user selection, Try the below code

```
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 5/*how many days from today*/); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "your title");
                    intent.putExtra("beginTime", calendar.getTime());
                    intent.putExtra("endTime", calendar.getTime() + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 30);
                    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, calendar.getTimeZone());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The date added (5 days in your example) needs to be based on which button they selected. It changes for each button. Can you help? I am guessing the number 5 would instead be a string value that was set on each button?

Comment: You can add any number of days you want to the calendar. If you want to set the reminder after 10 days, pass the value as 10. try to have some logic around to figure out which button user has clicked.

Comment: do `parseInt(String)` if you want to make that 5 a variable from a string.